# I have a clover-like plant in my garden, and I'm not sure if it is a weed

Tags: identification, weeds

I have a plant that is popping up everywhere in my garden and lawn, and I'm not sure if it is a weed. It looks like a clover but smaller(about half a feet) and has yellow flowers. It is in North Carolina, United States.
[image: 1]

Comment: If you don't want it , it is a weed.  Some of my weeds are 4 O'clock, violets, katy ruellia ,etc.

Comment: Just want to identify it.

Comment: One of the Oxalis species.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's wood sorrel, and it's usually considered a weed. In a lawn. any broadleaf herbicide will kill it, although the seeds already in the lawn will continue to sprout for years.

Comment: you can use Tenacity(R)  in early spring to stop those seeds from growing.